# Wi-fi connection down

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I'm on Windows 10 and sometimes, when I'm connected to a wifi network, Internet goes down and the wifi icon appears with a yellow triangle with "!". To turn on the network I have to reboot the computer, and after this, I can turn on.

Anyone knows what's happening?

Answer (score 1):

Might be driver related. Go to "Device Manager" and disable and re-enable the hardware, instead of using the apps that came with the pc.

Then try to update the drivers. If that doesn't solve your problem, might be hardware related. Grab a bootable cd/usb stick and boot it, if your problem persist, then it's hardware for sure.